# Тёртый калач - что означает?

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Почему его сравнивают с человеком и почему тёртый?

Answer (score 3):

Тёртый калач - калач из тёртого теста. Процесс его приготовления очень трудоёмкий. Калачи готовили 2 раза в год в форме гири (круглый каравай с ручкой, за которую можно его держать)и навешивали на ухват к потолку, где он высыхал, а потом его ели долго ещё и сухарём.Или замораживали.Чтобы калач долго хранился, ингредиенты(сахар, яйца, молоко)тщательно растирались,смешивались с мукой, чтобы тесто было очень густое, потом его замораживали и натирали на тёрке. Выпеченное изделие получалось пупырчатое и очень пышное, хранилось очень долго, не пропадало, не плесневело в отличие от смесного калача, на который тесто тщательно месили, но не натирали. Его срок хранения меньше.

Так что тёртый калач действительно проходил через многое, пока его приготовят, потому с ним и сравнивают опытного человека, прошедшего через многие испытания.

Кстати, "дойти до ручки" тоже отсюда пошло.Из соображений гигиены за дужку калача только держались, но никогда ее не ели, отдавали нищим или собакам.  «Дойти до ручки» - начать питаться дужками от калача, достигнуть крайней нищеты, потерять облик.

Comment: зашла случайно, искала про тертый калач. Хотела спросить -  откуда сведения, что тесто натирали на терке?

Answer (score 0):

Викисловарь говорит:

> От названия вида калача, сделанного из теста, которое предварительно долго мнут и трут. Отсюда же и пословица: не тёрт, не мят, не будет калач.

Comment: это как его трут?